# Eyeshot Devdept 2022 mesh simple cylinder surface

Tags: eyeshot

I am using Devdept 2022.

The problem is I cannot mesh a simple cylinderical surface without getting negative Jacobian errors.

Process:-
I am using is to convert surface to Brep, then Brep to mesh and finally mesh to femmesh. I cannot find a better way to directly mesh surfaces.

Code:-

```
using devDept;
using devDept.Eyeshot;
using devDept.Eyeshot.Entities;
using devDept.Eyeshot.Fem;
using devDept.Geometry;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Rotation = devDept.Eyeshot.Fem.Rotation;
using Material = devDept.Graphics.Material;

namespace NozzleSandbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FemMesh fm;
        private Simulation _currentSimulation;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //event handlers
            _currentSimulation = simulation1;
            _currentSimulation.WorkCompleted += simulation1_WorkCompleted;
            _currentSimulation.WorkFailed += _currentSimulation_WorkFailed;

        }

        private void _currentSimulation_WorkFailed(object sender, WorkFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void simulation1_WorkCompleted(object sender, WorkCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.WorkUnit is SolverBase)
            {
                _currentSimulation.ActiveViewport.Legends[0].IsSlave = true;

                // Changes the Legend color box size
                _currentSimulation.ActiveViewport.Legends[0].ItemSize = new Size(9, 18);

                SolverBase solver = (SolverBase)e.WorkUnit;

                FemMesh fm = solver.Mesh;

                // computes the selected plot
                fm.PlotMode = FemMesh.plotType.VonMises;
                //fm.PlotMode = FemMesh.plotType.Uy;

                fm.NodalAverages = true;

                fm.ComputePlot(simulation1, simulation1.ActiveViewport.Legends[0], true);

                simulation1.ZoomFit();

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TestCylinder();

            SolveSetup();
        }

        private void TestCylinder()
        {
            //use material steel
            Material mat = Material.StructuralSteel;
            mat.ElementThickness = 2;       //2mm thickness


            //draw circle for cylinder cs
            Circle c1 = new Circle(Plane.XY, new Point3D(0, 0, 0), 50);

            //extrude as a surface this circle c1
            Surface cs = c1.ExtrudeAsSurface(250);

            Brep csBrep = cs.ConvertToBrep();

            Mesh msh = csBrep.ConvertToMesh(5, false);

            fm = msh.ConvertToFemMesh(mat, true);

            int numFaces = fm.SetPressure(Plane.ZX, 55, 0.155);

            fm.FixAll(Plane.XY, 0.5);


        }

        private void SolveSetup()
        {
            Solver solver = new Solver(fm);

            _currentSimulation.StartWork(solver);
        }

    }
}
```

I think its better for such a library to provide powerful methods to work with surfaces as surfaces models are lightweight and require much less resources and time to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 2D Triangle element in a 3D FEM mesh. You need a 3D Shell or Membrane elements to resolve this problem.